# Can textures once uploaded from CPU/Main Memory/RAM to GPU be deallocated on CPU?

Tags: opengl, webgl

For a fixed 3D scene with animations (which cannot be partially loaded into memory), with say 1000 objects and various zoom levels, once all the textures have been uploaded to the GPU, do their data still need to be held on the CPU, essentially the application works even if deallocate all the texture data from the CPU/Main RAM, but is this totally safe, or they should still be continued to be held in main memory apart from the GPU memory?

Comment: It's safe with OpenGL.  With DirectX you can get something called "lost device", which would require you recreate all textures (if your textures aren't "managed").  OpenGL backs them in system memory so they're never lost.

Comment: [**WebGL** *can* loose its device context due to various reasons requiring you to recreate all GPU resources and states.](https://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/HandlingContextLost)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After sending them to OpenGL, all cpu data can be deleted without any problems. This is true for textures as well as for buffers.

If the implementation does not upload the data immediately to the gpu (afaik all desktop GL implementation delay that), then the OpenGL implementation has to make sure that cpu data is backed up until needed.

Comment: What about the behavior of WebGL (on Chrome and Firefox)

Comment: @seahorse Its the same, once you called `bufferData`, `texImage` or what ever, you can do with the CPU buffers whatever you want without any side effects. In the future please tag your question with one API only, WebGL and OpenGL are **not** the same making your question ambiguous.